# Generate and return an image within Silverstripe Framework

Tags: php, image, httprequest, httpresponse, silverstripe

I am trying to generate and return an image to the template using the Silverstripe 3.0 Framework and am getting some issues.

I return this to the browser in a variable like so:

```
public function make_image(){

    $string = 'string';
    $im     = imagecreate(300,300);
    $orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
    $px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
    imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

}
```

The browser renders this as:

`` �PNG  IHDR,,C�6PLTE��<��*�"IDATh���1 �Om ?�x-��{�IEND�B`� ``

The headers that are being returned are text/html and there is only one request that makes me think there is something strange going on there. Can anyone help me out with this.

Possibly a different way of achieving this is Silverstripe using the Image() class?

Comment: Try `header("Content-type: image/png");`

Comment: I have, the headers in Silverstripe are set before the template is rendered.

Comment: `<img src="my_image.png" type="image/png" />` There's not much info on this, but can't hurt to try to force the image to show correct on output. Are you writing the file to the server first or instantly putting it on the page? If I do this in my Terminal; `file -b my_png_file.png` it outputs; `PNG image data, 1920 x 1080, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced`. As you are using a CMS, it might be that your headers are already sent. Try enabling `error_reporting('E_ALL');` and see if that's the case. Very common issue. You can only use image headers when you are fetching a PHP as an image tho.

Comment: With that I mean that the header will make the whole PHP page rendered as such. So if you do `header("Content-type: image/png");` you can only give back the image, and not extra content. Something like this would be the result; `<img src="my_image.php" />`.

Comment: @Allendar I am trying to output it straight to the page but I am unsure if that is the correct way. I am going to test what you suggested and the answer below.

Comment: Daniel Tate: as the solution posted by @jfbarrois below seems to solve your problem, please mark it as accepted. shows your appreciation, helps finding unsolved silverstripe questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too sure why you need to play with your http headers. I understand you're going through intermediary steps to generate your image, so you need to see it being generated, but if your initial goal is to generate an image to include it in a template, this might help:

```
public function StringImage($string) {
    $filePath = ASSETS_PATH.'/'.$string.'.png';
    if (!file_exists(ASSETS_PATH.'/'.$string.'.png')){
        $stringFontSize = 11;
        $dimensions = imagettfbbox($stringFontSize, 90, 'Arial', $string);
        $gd = new GD();
        $width = $dimensions[2] - $dimensions[4];
        $height = $dimensions[7] - $dimensions[5];
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width, $height, 0xFFFFFF);
        imagettftext($image, $stringFontSize, 90, $width, $height, 0x000000, 'Arial', $string);
        $gd->setGD($image);
        $gd->writeTo($filePath);
    }
    return '<img src="'.ASSETS_DIR.'/'.$string.'.png'.'" alt="string"/>';
}
```

Comment: Cool. It might be worth noting for anyone who wants to use the code above that the $string variable should be sanitized somehow before being used as a file name. This was just a proof of concept.

Comment: @DanielTate If the answer worked perfectly you should accept it.